# .txt en lista a un arreglo

Tags: java, array

Me pueden ayudar por favor, tengo que pasa una lista de 25 números en Java a un arreglo bi-
dimensional, así.
El .txt debe ir en formato de lista:

1

2

3

y así hasta el 25

Tengo este código pero no funciona bien:

```
public class Examen {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String linea;
    File archivo = null;
    FileReader Fr = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        archivo = new File("C:\\Users\\Paulina Araguz\\Desktop\\Entrada.txt"); // Ruta desde donde se lee el txt
        Fr = new FileReader(archivo.toString());
        br = new BufferedReader(Fr);

        String matriz[][] = new String[5][5]; // Lectura de matriz 5*5

        while (((linea = br.readLine()) != null)) {
            System.out.println("=Prueba=");
            for (int filas = 0; filas < 1; filas++) {
                for (int columnas = 0; columnas < 5; columnas++) {
                    matriz[filas][columnas] = linea;
                    System.out.println(matriz[filas][columnas]);
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
     }
   }
}
```

[image: Imprensión de consola]

Soy principiante en Java yo se que es muy sencillo pero no logro entenderlo agradecería mucho la ayuda de alguien con más conocimiento. Gracias.

Comment: Exactamente... ¿cuál es el problema con tu código?

Comment: estimado que es lo que necesitas hacer con arreglo , no explicas que es lo que deseas hacer, saludos

Comment: Disculpa si no es muy claro mira necesito que tome los numeros en lista desde el archivo .txt, los debe tomar enlistados asi:                                                                1                                                                                                                            2...hasta el 25                                                                                                                                                                                                
 hasta el 25 y ponerlos en el arreglo de 5x5

Comment: Ordena mal mis numeros, es mas ni siquiera los lee apropiadamente, estoy bastante perdido ya que solo se me pide que los lea de una lista y los ponga en un arreglo de 5*5 ya hice muchas pruebas y no logro hacer que funcione, como vez lo unico que hace es tomar la lista e imprimirla en los 5 renglones cuando lo que quiero es que se detenga en el quinto numero, salte de renglo e imprima los otros 5, para formar la matriz de 5*5

Answer (score 2):

El `for` de las filas debe llegar hasta el tamaño de dicha fila, es decir 5 no hasta 1.

Adicionalmente propondría poner un condicional dentro de los `for` anidados e ir llenando cada posición con el valor de cada linea del archivo, en vez del `while` externo.

El cambio en las lineas es apenas sustancial pero significativo en el flujo de ejecución.

```
//while (((linea = br.readLine()) != null)) {
  System.out.println("=Prueba=");
  for (int filas = 0; filas < 5; filas++) {
      for (int columnas = 0; columnas < 5; columnas++) {
         if((linea=br.readLine()) != null) {
           matriz[filas][columnas] = linea;
         }
         System.out.print(matriz[filas][columnas]+"\t");
      }
      System.out.println();
  }
//}
```

Lo anterior arrojaria una salida similar a:

```
=Prueba=
1   2   3   4   5
6   7   8   9   10
11  12  13  14  15
16  17  18  19  20
21  22  23  24  25
```

Comment: Lo pruebo y le digo como fue, gracias por lo ayuda

Comment: Funciono perfecto, te agradezco mucho, ademas entendí perfecto, gracias.